# Weblogic 12 relative path in log4j property using ${} not working

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic12c

I set a system variable `loghome= some valid path` in weblogic start shell script on my Aix box. The same variable is used in my log4J property file inside jar which my application uses.

`log4j.appender.file.File=${loghome}/xyz.log`

When starting the server , there is an exception thrown as below

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /xyz.log (Permission denied)

The relative path is not working anymore *(meaning xyz.log won't get updated or not generated if not present earlier)*.  I am using log4J version 1.2.9.(Cannot upgrade log4J as of now , so need to resolve with this version)

Things i observed

- `echo ${loghome}` inside my shell script displays the path correctly .
- The actual path *instead of using ${loghome}* inside log4J property works fine updating the log without any exception. (unfortunately cannot resolve using this method)
- Permissions/privileges of both the shell script and the jar having property file are same.
- This has happened ever since the server upgraded from WL11 to WL12.

Any suggestions on what to check or how to fix please ?

Comment: Do you `export`  this variable in your script?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Yes it is exported.